# Instantiate a class object in startup.cs in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, startup, dependency-inversion

I am trying to pass an interface and settings into a class while creating an instance of that class in startup.cs in .Net Core Project. I am using the below code to do so. I have some code written in the constructor of Student class but while starting the application **the Code/Logic inside the constructor** is not working. There is no error but the debug pointer is not hitting the constructor of Student class.

```
services.AddSingleton(c => new Student(settings, resourceSetting, c.GetService<IPersonService>()));
```

If I am using the below code then the code inside Student constructor is working fine.

```
 Student studentHandler = new Student(settings, resourceSetting,);
 services.AddSingleton<Student>(studentHandler);
```

But I need to pass Service interface in the constructor to do some work while starting the Project. Can anyone help me with what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Why do you expect constructor to be called in that case? You explicitly decided to use on-demand creation version and you seem to disagree with your own choice...

Comment: you should include the snippet where you're attempting to use\initialize this singleton 'Student' service type.  the first snippet is potentially lazyloading (deferred execution to resolve that dependency).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the debug pointer is not hitting the constructor of Student class

That's because you're registering the type as an implementation factory in the first snippet, using [`AddSingleton<TService> (this IServiceCollection services, Func<IServiceProvider,TService> implementationFactory)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Func_System_IServiceProvider___0__) With this method, the implementation factory delegate (and subsequently the `Student` constructor) won't be called *until the dependency is resolved*.

In the second snippet, you're directly instantiating the type at service registration and adding that instance to the service collection with [`AddSingleton<TService> (this IServiceCollection services, TService implementationInstance)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection___0_).

---

Here's an example with logs explaining each step in each approach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        RegisterImplementationFactory();
        RegisterImplementation();
    }

    static void RegisterImplementationFactory()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RegisterImplementationFactory ------------");

        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        Console.WriteLine("Registering Student...");
        services.AddSingleton(c => new Student());
        Console.WriteLine("Student registered.");

        Console.WriteLine("Building ServiceProvider...");
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceProvider built.");

        Console.WriteLine("Resolving Student...");
        Student student = serviceProvider.GetService<Student>();
        Console.WriteLine("Student resolved.");

        Console.WriteLine("RegisterImplementationFactory ------------");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    static void RegisterImplementation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RegisterImplementation ------------");

        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        Console.WriteLine("Registering Student...");
        Student studentToRegister = new Student();
        services.AddSingleton(studentToRegister);
        Console.WriteLine("Student registered.");

        Console.WriteLine("Building ServiceProvider...");
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        Console.WriteLine("ServiceProvider built.");

        Console.WriteLine("Resolving Student...");
        Student student = serviceProvider.GetService<Student>();
        Console.WriteLine("Student resolved.");

        Console.WriteLine("RegisterImplementation ------------");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("!!! Instantiating Student...");
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
RegisterImplementationFactory ------------
Registering Student...
Student registered.
Building ServiceProvider...
ServiceProvider built.
Resolving Student...
!!! Instantiating Student...
Student resolved.
RegisterImplementationFactory ------------

RegisterImplementation ------------
Registering Student...
!!! Instantiating Student...
Student registered.
Building ServiceProvider...
ServiceProvider built.
Resolving Student...
Student resolved.
RegisterImplementation ------------
```

With this you can clearly see that when registering using the factory delegate, the `Student` constructor isn't called until the type is resolved (with `GetService<Student>()` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Dependency Injection, so I would recommend based on your constructor to further make use of the DI engine.

First, you will want to register the `settings` and `resourceSetting` objects

```
services.AddSingleton<Student>(settings);
services.AddSingleton<Student>(resourceSetting);
```

Then register your `Student` class as well

```
services.AddSingleton<Student>();
```

And now once you build your `ServiceCollection` into the `ServiceProvider` via `.BuildServiceProvider();` (If you are doing a console app) you can call:

`var myStudent = myServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Student>();`

If you are doing this in something like asp.net, then you would simply just inject your `Student` class into a controller or other such service for consumption

```
class MyController : ControllerBase
{

    private Student Student { get; }

    public MyController(Student student)
    {
       Student = student ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(student));
    }
 
    ...
}
```